# Create Android project from the command line

Tags: android, command-line, emacs

Is there any tool, to create a Android project form the command line?

There was the tool android from the command line tools to do this. This tool is no longer supported.

I would like to do the complete development from emacs. With the actual command line tools, it is only possible to build and debug.

Comment: `I would like to do the complete development from emacs` - why?

Comment: Because I find the navigation in android studio horrible. In emacs with the keyboard I can navigate a lot faster. Also I find the user interface in android studio way to overload. I like to see just a big screen with nothing but my code.

Comment: Can you not create a new project with Android Studio,  then just use Emacs after it is generated - just use Android studio for the initial generation. Android Studio is the industry standard and maybe is worth getting more comfortable with, you can do a lot of customisation with it to Taylor it more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions that come to my mind (and all of them are alternatively good in varying degrees):

1. Create a new command line tool that creates an android project using [IntelliJ API](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/) of Android Studio.
2. Use [GUI automation scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools). That option is awkward but works for these who can't make themselve program in Java. Depending on your platform you can use:

   - [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) for macOS
   - [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for Windows
   - Something else (Tcl/Tk/expect or Python and tinter or [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io) or maybe  [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/), [Cobra](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra), [PyATOM](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom).)
3. Do nothing and just wait until googlers create such a command line tool themselves.